# Push metrics to Prometheus Pushgateway from AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, prometheus

I have an application that I have to monitor every 5 mins. However, that application does not have a /metrics port for Prometheus to directly scrape from and I don't have any control over that application.

As a workaround, I wrote a python program to manually scrape the data, and transforms those data to my own metrics such as gauge and counters. Then I pushed those metrics to pushgateway for Prometheus to scrape from.

Everything worked fine at local. Now, I want to take a step further by using the AWS Lambda function to pull data and generate metrics for me every 5 mins(so I don't have to keep the python program running on my laptop).

My question would be, instead of using:

```
push_to_gateway(gateway='localhost:9091', job="Monitor", registry=registry)
```

to push my metrics to pushgateway, what would this be in the lambda function? Also, I believe the pushgateway should be hosted somewhere for AWS to access. How do we achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your use case correctly, but you might want to look into using the `text_collector` from Prometheus' node_exporter.  The repository contains [a simple example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/node_exporter/29d4629f55603001e25fea65e8cb593b86e58f47/text_collector_examples/pacman.sh).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the lambda and run it every 5 minutes with a cloudwatch rule. Inside the lambda, instead of calling push_to_gateway, you can just curl the pushgateway. see and example [here](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#command-line).
Make sure that the gateway is accessible from the lambda - either behind a public ELB or have them both in the same vpc.